# Copying Multiple Columns from Worksheets to a single Worksheet

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I am interested in copying multiple columns from multiple sheets to a single sheet. Basically, I have water utilization data on 22 sheets. Each one of these sheets contains utilization data pertaining to **a particular day in the month** and **all the sheets have the same formatting**. So, I am interested in copying the utilization columns (let's suppose I,K,N and P) from each one of these 22 sheets and then paste it in a summary sheet so that I can have the **utilization data from each day** in a **single sheet**. The output that i'm looking for on my summary sheet is - (columns I,K,N,P - from Day1); (columns I,K,N,P - from Day2) so on and so forth.

I would appreciate any help in this regard. 
Many thanks. :)

Answer (score 2):

1. In your summary sheet, select A1 and type the equal sign.
2. select your first day sheet and select K1 and press enter.
   (now the value in K1 in Day1 should be in summary sheet cell A1)
3. In summary sheet, drag A1 down to show all data you need.
4. Repeat process for all columns in all sheets.

Now you have a working summary sheet that you can copy/paste into your next month summary sheet also instead of repeating the copy/paste process.

PS:  Better yet, choose column I and copy column A to the right until you reach the data in column P.  Then delete the columns you do not need.  You can just copy the Formula in A1 to E1 and change the sheet name in the formula and repeat the process.

Answer (score 0):

You could start by recording a `macro` while you perform these actions manually, and then look at the `VBA` generated by the macro to find the areas you'd like to automate.  What have you tried so far?